# Dynamically choose a column to query in Redshift

Tags: sql, dynamic, amazon-redshift

I want to take a one-string query response to populate a SELECT statement in another query.  Some say it's impossible, but Redshift makes fools of us all.

Imagine I have a table day_of_week as follows:

```
Day of Week | Weekend
---------------------
  Monday    | No
  Tuesday   | No
  Wednesday | No
  Thursday  | No
  Friday    | No
  Saturday  | Yes
  Sunday    | Yes
```

And another party_time like this:

```
Yes          | No
--------------------------
All the time | None of the time
```

I want to allow someone to just tell me a day (eg, "Wednesday") and then use the resulting Weekend value to query of party_time.

eg

```
SELECT (SELECT Weekend FROM day_of_week WHERE "Day of Week" = 'Wednesday')
FROM party_time
```

Result: 'None of the time'

How?

Comment: Perhaps there is some clever technique using UNPIVOT to turn column names into values which could work for you, but that is beyond my capabilities ATM.

Answer (score 1):

SQL itself isn't dynamic/self-referential although most implementations have some sort of meta language to partly get around that.

The most obvious solution for your problem is to change table party_time:

```
Test    Meaning
--------------------------
Yes     All the time
No      None of the time
```

Then you can use a join or a sub-select to get to your answer:

```
select meaning
from party_time
inner join day_of_week
on weekend = test
where Day_of_Week = 'Wednesday'
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f10b7/1

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  I was trying to make a toy example.  In reality, I have a table that has four columns: index + 3 stats for hundreds of objects.  I have a user interface that can pick which stat to display.  So I really just want to pass that variable to query and only pull the relevant stat.